# FBX Model has no walls inside in Unity – why is that

Tags: unity

I have an FBX file which I import in Unity. If I go inside the Model, the walls are not visible. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably backface culling.

Blender doesn't cull backfaces by default, meaning your still able to see the mesh even when you look at polygons from the "wrong" side. This is what it looks like when you enable it.

[image]

You can solve this by adding some "solid" geometry with a solidify modifier to give the walls two out-facing normals.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to do this in Cinema4d? Cause I don't use blender…

Comment: This is a blender help forum. I have not used C4D, but very briefly.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, in every 3D software a face has only one side and is not visible from the other side. It only 'exists' in the direction of its normal. Most softwares have the option to enable "two sided" (or disable "backface culling"), making the faces visible from both sides. Effectively what the software is doing is duplicating every face and flipping the normals, making it appear that faces have two sides. For 'real time' applications like games, this can have a considerable negative effect on performance if it's overused.

That being said, both Unity and Unreal have material settings that enable 'two sided', but it's not recommended to overuse it, for perfomance reasons.
It's usually best to just model the interior faces only where they'll be seen by the user/player. In the case of your model I assume the player would only be able to see a little bit inside the cylinder/pipe that comes out of the capsule, so you'd just need to create interior faces on that part of the mesh.